# почему возвращает только последний элемент?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

Почему не принтует весь результат цикла, а только последний его элемент ?

```
browser.get(link)
time.sleep(2)
js="""
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName('vqA6QljR2KNt8yw9PHk9C');for 
(var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++){var price += 
priceEls[i].innerText;console.log(price);} return price;
"""
q = browser.execute_script(js)

print(q)
```

=================
проблема решена, готовый код ниже :

```
browser.get(link)
time.sleep(2)
js="""
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName('vqA6QljR2KNt8yw9PHk9C');
let price = [];
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++){price.push( 
priceEls[i].innerText);console.log(price);} return price;
"""
q = browser.execute_script(js)

print(q)
```

Comment: Буду благодарен, если вы отметите правильное решение задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы перезаписываете значение, а не добавляете. Сделайте += и должно работать:

```
browser.get(link)
time.sleep(2)
js="""
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName('vqA6QljR2KNt8yw9PHk9C');
var price = '';
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++){price += 
priceEls[i].innerText;console.log(price);} return price;
"""
q = browser.execute_script(js)

print(q)
```

Comment: Message: javascript error: Unexpected token '+='

Comment: Потому что вынесите переменную за цикл var price = "". При первой итерации там ничего нет.

Comment: как сделать, чтобы данные на выходе не слипались ? 07:00 - 08:5008:00 - 09:5008:00 - такой вывод щас, а надо 07:00 - 08:50 08:00 - 09:50 08:00

Comment: @user366600 записывать за `console.log(price)` символ табуляции/перехода строки?)

Comment: или чтобы каждая запись на отдельной строке записывалась, для этого в каком месте нужно \n прописать ?

Comment: console.log(price); \n}   - не работает

Comment: Message: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @user366600 подумайте только о том, что если вам придется обращаться к каждому из элементов лога, то вам придется парсить строку `price`, поэтому вам лучше использовать массив, чтобы вы могли обращаться к каждой записи отдельно

Comment: @user366600 заведите массив и используйте `.push()` для каждого нового сообщения, а затем возвращайте его

Comment: логично, т.е вместо var price = ' '; сделать price [] или как в js объявляются массивы? и к сожалению перенос строки не работает

Comment: @user366600 Посмотрите объявление массивов в `js` в документации. Тут за вас никто полностью код писать не будет:) Был задан вопрос - на него дали ответ

Comment: я Вас понял, проверьте код, сделал по Вашему совету, вроде бы работает! спасибо за терпение и советы!

Comment: @user366600 не надо вставлять рабочий код заместо нерабочего, когда решили проблему:) Иначе тем, кто будет искать в дальнейшем аналогичную проблему, не сможет увидеть, что было ДО

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `console.log(price);` выводит отладочную информацию в консоль, т.е. скрывая ее от пользователей.

А в консоль питона вы выводите только `return price;`, то есть последнее значение.

Comment: а как вывести все значения в консоль питона ?

Comment: @user366600 Сделать, чтобы `price` был массивом и возвращать его